# How can I delete empty line from my ouput by grep?

Tags: bash

Exists way to remove empty lines with `cat myfile | grep -w #something` ?

I looking for simple way for remove empty lines from my output like in the way the presented above.

Comment: Why do you need `-w` in it?

Comment: @thatotherguy because that I want all the line apart of `empty line` , so I looking for `something` that can do it..

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe your output to `awk` to easily remove empty lines

```
cat myfile | grep -w #something | awk NF
```

EDIT: so... you just want `cat myfile | awk NF`?

if you have to use grep, you can do `grep myfile -v '^[[:blank:]]*$'`

Comment: I am looking for `something` that can for treat this proble, for example, something like " "  (instead `something` ) but it's not working with " " ..

Comment: why don't you want to use awk?

Comment: I thought for example about that: `cat myfile | grep -w " " ` .. but it's not working..

Comment: And I don't want `awk` because   I try to understand how to do it (if at all) by `grep` ..

Comment: @Software_t, see edit

Answer (score 0):

This really belongs on the codegolfing stackexchange because it's not related to how anyone would ever write a script. However, you can do it like this:

```
cat myfile | grep -w '.*..*'
```

It's equivalent to the more canonical `grep .`, but adds explicit `.*`s on either side so that it will always match the complete line, thereby satisfying the word boundary conditions imposed by `-w`